# CUDA recursion depth

Tags: recursion, cuda, dynamic-parallelism

When using **Dynamic Parallelism** in *CUDA*, you can implement recursive algorithms like *mergeSort*. I have implemented it and my program don't work for inputs greater than *blah*.
My question is how many depth in the recursion tree the implementation can go? Is there any limitation? (My program is just fine for smaller inputs.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301903/cuda-5-x-on-kepler-dynamic-kernel-execution-and-maximum-recursion-depth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From *Professional CUDA C Programming*:

> The maximum nesting depth of dynamic parallelism is limited to 24, but in reality most kernels will be limited by the amount of memory required by the device runtime system at each new level . . .

Comment: This is documented in [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#nesting-and-synchronization-depth) as well.

Comment: Seems like something that will need to go in the `cudaDeviceProp` struct eventually.